# What is this liquid/anything to be concerned about?

Tags: battery

[image]

As you can see there is a cable with some syrup coloured gunge or whatever on it, on close inspection it actually looks like it’s coming out of the wire.
 The cable itself I think goes from the fuse box(I’m guessing battery fuse) and joins to the positive  battery terminal as you can see in the picture, unless I have confused it with the second cable which went underneath the engine somewhere though I mostly sure this went to the fuse box.

What is this substance and is it anything to worry about/take action with?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear to be coming out of the wire and I suspect that it's glue or sealant that was put in to keep the elements out of the wire.  If that's the whole of it I doubt that it's a problem.  My only concern might be a loose connection there on the battery that is causing the terminal and wire to heat up and cause the stuff to bubble out.

Check and clean the connection there although it looks clean in the photo.

Comment: there was indeed a loose connection on that cable which had been there for a while and I had just fixed today before noticing and taking this pic .  Are you saying I should just leave it as is now, without the need to wipe or put any sealent back in? thanks

Comment: @JamesWilson  At this point I would leave it.  Only a small amount appears to have leaked out and I suspect that it's still sealed well enough.  If you notice it starting to corrode down the road you can always replace it later.